# Verifying equation 4 in Ekert's paper "Quantum Cryptography Based on Bell's Theorem"

Tags: bell-experiment

[Ekert's 1999 paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.67.661) ([link to download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xp6Z8j04aF-BOdHODTk83khATlc7fD3H/view?usp=sharing)) cites the classic CHSH paper on generalized Bell inequality and says

(2) $E(a,b)=-a\cdot b$

(3) $S = E(a_1,b_1)-E(a_1,b_3)+E(a_3,b_1)_E(a_3,b_3)$

(4) $S = -2\sqrt(2)$ This is the CSHS score

They state that for certain choices of a and b from $a\in\{0,\pi/4,\pi/2\}$ and $b\in\{\pi/4,\pi/2,3\pi/4\}$, equation 4 holds. Not having read the paper carefully enough, I believed that a and b were random angles on the unit circle. When I calculated it that way, equation (4) was not satified. That is why I posted the question.

However, for $a_1=0, a_3=\pi/2,b_1=\pi.4,b_2=3\pi/4$, it is satisfied.

Comment: $S = - 2\sqrt{2}$ only for a specific set of angles. However for all angles you will have $|S| \leq 2 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: What makes you say that (4) holds regardless of the values of a,b? You can only achieve that specific value with very specific relative directions of the a and b vectors.

Comment: Well I tried a range of angles from 0 to 2 pi and the biggest magnitude I got was 2.0, which admittedly is $\le2\sqrt(2)$

Comment: Try $\pi/4$ intervals rather than $\pi/3$.

Comment: Also there's an error in how you coded the CHSH score. It should be `e(a1,b1)-e(a1,b3)+e(a3,b1)+e(a3,b3)`. In the current code the two middle terms cancel so you will never achieve anything beyond $2$.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error. With 31 angles on the unit circle and e(a1,b1)-e(a1,b3)+e(a3,b1)+e(a3,b3), I still never get beyond 2. If I can edit my question I will put in the amended code

Answer (score 0):

The CHSH formulas only hold for very specific angles; when I saw that I updated the question and gave the angles for which (4) was satisfied.